# How to require folder with inherited classes?

Tags: ruby

I have a directory with classes which inherits each other:

```
# auth_serializer.rb
class AuthSerializer < UserSerializer
end

# user_serializer.rb
class UserSerializer
end
```

I require it this way:

```
Dir[File.expand_path('./**/*.rb', __dir__)].each do |f|
  require f
end
```

And have an error:

```
  uninitialized constant UserSerializer
  # ./app/serializers/auth_serializer.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

I understand why this error happens - because **AuthSerializer** required before **UserSerializer**. How to require a bunch of files without this error? I don't want to rename `user_serializer.rb` into `0_user_serializer.rb` or make custom order of require for each time when this error happens.

Comment: Why don't you require `UserSerializer` in `AuthSerializer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `require` will load needed file only once, there will be no harm to make this structure:

```
# auth_serializer.rb
require_relative 'user_serializer'
class AuthSerializer < UserSerializer
end

# user_serializer.rb
class UserSerializer
end
```

It will fix your problem and allow to require only `auth_serializer` if needed.